# Creating multi-language document

Tags: table-of-contents, babel, languages

I am trying to write a document in both English and French (like the ones you can find on some planes). I use following declaration to use `babel`:

```
\usepackage[english,frenchb]{babel}
\babeltags{en = english}
\babeltags{fr = frenchb}
```

This works nice for paragraphs and typography.

Now I also want to add titles (`\sections`). I followed this previous answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/170963/27327. This allows to create 2 different Table of contents, but only French titles are shown in the document (all `\addetoc` ones are dismissed).

So is there a simple way to create multi-language documents?

What I want is something like:

The TOC page:

```
|------------------------+-------------------------|
| table of content       | Table des matieres      |
|------------------------+-------------------------|
| Fist section         3 | Première section      3 |
| Second section      10 | Deuxième section     10 |
| ...                    | ...                     |
|                        |                         |
|------------------------+-------------------------|
```

On a `\section` page:

```
|--------------------------------------------------|
| First Section  -  Première Section             3 |
|--------------------------------------------------|
| Text in English                                  |
|                                                  |
|--------------------------------------------------|
| Text in French                                   |
|                                                  |
|--------------------------------------------------|
```

The only things I am missing are:

- how to display a section in several languages
- how to display a 2-column toc in the same page (one for each language)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For the `ToC` see my answer here please: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/300169/two-column-layout-with-bilingual-two-tables-of-contents-for-each-language

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thanks that solved the first part of my problem. I don't see though how to display section titles in both languages.

Comment: I didn't claim it would solve the section issue :-P, I wrote `for the ToC...` What is the `3` in the section header? The page number?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Yes 3 is a page number. BTW I guess http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/237637/how-to-create-a-table-of-authorship may also be a part of the solution.

Comment: Do you provide the section titles or are they auto generated, i.e. 1st section, 2nd section, without any special name?

Comment: I provide them. I guess I have to dig into the `\latex@@section` and `\@startsection` commands

Comment: I try to solve it. `\@startsection` is of no real use here

Answer (score 3):

Something like this perhaps? (warning, the section title does not wrap around correctly!)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,frenchb]{babel}
\babeltags{en = english}
\babeltags{fr = frenchb}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{xparse}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{parcolumns}




\makeatletter

\patchcmd{\pc@placeboxes}{\vrule}{{\VRULE}}{}{}
\newcommand\VRULE{\color{SOME_COLOR}\vrule width 0.2mm}



\def\@sect#1#2#3#4#5#6[#7]#8{%
  \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth
    \let\@svsec\@empty
  \else
    \refstepcounter{#1}%
    \protected@edef\@svsec{\@seccntformat{#1}\relax}%
  \fi
  \@tempskipa #5\relax
  \ifdim \@tempskipa>\z@
    \begingroup
      #6{%
        \@hangfrom{\hskip #3\relax}%\@svsec}
          \interlinepenalty \@M  #8 \hfill\thepage\@@par}%
    \endgroup
    \csname #1mark\endcsname{#7}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{#1}{%
      \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth \else
        \protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}%
      \fi
      #7}%
  \else
    \def\@svsechd{%
      #6{\hskip #3\relax
      \@svsec #8}%
      \csname #1mark\endcsname{#7}%
      \addcontentsline{toc}{#1}{%
        \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth \else
          \protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}%
        \fi
        #7}}%
  \fi
  \@xsect{#5}}



\let\latex@@section\section
\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{somo}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
    \latex@@section*{#3}%
  }{%
    \def\@temp@@a{#3}
    \IfValueT{#4}{%
      \xdef\@temp@@a{#3 -- #4}
    }
    \IfValueTF{#2}{%
      \latex@@section[#2]{\@temp@@a}%
    }{%
      \latex@@section[#3]{\@temp@@a}
    }%
    \IfValueT{#4}{%
      \addcontentsline{ftoc}{section}{\protect\numberline{\csname thesection\endcsname}#4}
    }%
  }%
}



\renewcommand\tableofcontents[1][toc]{%
  \section*{\contentsname
    \@mkboth{%
      \MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}%
  \@starttoc{#1}%
}



\makeatother  

\begin{document}

\begin{parcolumns}[nofirstindent,rulebetween=true]{2}
    \colchunk{%
        \selectlanguage{english}
        \tableofcontents
    }
    \colchunk{%
      \selectlanguage{french}
      \tableofcontents[ftoc]
    }
\end{parcolumns}
\pagebreak

\section{First section}[Première Section]
\selectlanguage{english}
\blindtext
\selectlanguage{frenchb}
\blindtext
\section{Second Section}[Deuxième Section]
\selectlanguage{english}
\blindtext

\selectlanguage{frenchb}
\blindtext


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That do the job. Thanks. BTW `\color{SOME_COLOR}` generate an error. But the rest is correct. I'll see if I can find a workaround for the wrap.

Comment: @renard: The `\color{SOME_COLOR}` works out of the box for me, because the `\VRULE` command is never actually.

Answer (score 0):

Using following macro does the job for me:

```
\newlength{\sect@@width}
\usepackage{calc}
\newcommand\mlsection[2]{%
  \refstepcounter{section}
  \begingroup
  \def\temp@@a{\noindent{#1}\hfill{#1}}
  \setlength{\sect@@width}{\widthof{\temp@@a}}
  \ifdim \sect@@width>\textwidth
  \noindent#1\newline
  \noindent#2
  \else
  \temp@@a
  \fi
  \endgroup
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{\csname thesection\endcsname}#1}
  \addcontentsline{ftoc}{section}{\protect\numberline{\csname thesection\endcsname}#2}
}%
```

beware: this is NOT a generic solution it does handle section numbering numbering (except in the TOC) or formating.

EDIT: The TOC links in the generated PDF doc does not work well either. Only links from the `toc` table are shown, `ftoc` links are not.

EDIT2:
I eventually found a minimalistic working solution (no par skip, widow, club etc) but links in PDF document work:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,frenchb]{babel}
\babeltags{en = english}
\babeltags{fr = frenchb}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{xparse}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{parcolumns}

\usepackage{bookmark}



\makeatletter


\usepackage{printlen}
\newlength{\sect@@width}
\usepackage{calc}
\newcommand\@mlsection[4]{%
  \refstepcounter{section}%
  \begingroup%
  \currentpdfbookmark{#1}{section.\csname thesection\endcsname}%
  \currentpdfbookmark{#2}{section.\csname thesection\endcsname}%
  \vspace{1em}%
  \def\temp@@a{\LARGE\noindent{#3}\hfill{#4}}%
  \setlength{\sect@@width}{\widthof{\temp@@a}}%
  \ifdim \sect@@width>\textwidth%
  \noindent\LARGE#3\newline%
  \noindent\LARGE#4%
  \else%
  \temp@@a%
  \fi%
  \newline
  \endgroup%
  \addcontentsline{entoc}{section}{\protect\numberline{\csname thesection\endcsname}#1}%
  \addcontentsline{frtoc}{section}{\protect\numberline{\csname thesection\endcsname}#2}%
}%

\newcommand\mlsection[2]{%
  \begingroup%
  \@mlsection{#1}{#2}{\selectlanguage{english}#1}{\selectlanguage{frenchb}#2}%
  \endgroup%
}%

\renewcommand\tableofcontents[1][toc]{%
  \section*{\contentsname
    \@mkboth{%
      \MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}%
  \@starttoc{#1}%
}

\makeatother



\begin{document}

\begin{parcolumns}[nofirstindent,rulebetween=true]{2}
    \colchunk{
        \selectlanguage{frenchb}
        \tableofcontents[frtoc]
        %\shorttableofcontents{\contentsname}{1}
    }
    \colchunk{
        \selectlanguage{english}
        \tableofcontents[entoc]
    }
\end{parcolumns}

\newpage

\mlsection{First section}{Première Section}
{\selectlanguage{english}\blindtext}

{\selectlanguage{frenchb}\blindtext}

\mlsection{Second Section}{Deuxième Section}
{\selectlanguage{english}\blindtext}

{\selectlanguage{frenchb}\blindtext}

\mlsection{Third Section}{Troisième Section}
{\selectlanguage{english}\blindtext}

{\selectlanguage{frenchb}\blindtext}

\mlsection{Fourth Section}{Quatrième Section}
{\selectlanguage{english}\blindtext}

{\selectlanguage{frenchb}\blindtext}

\end{document}
```

the trick is to use `toc` to generate the anchors (`section.N`) and `\currentpdfbookmark` to create PDF links pointing to `section.N`. OTOH create both `entoc` and `frtoc` to display dual language table of content.

Comment: Your question did **not** reveal that you wanted `bookmarks` for the 2nd language as well. Using portions of code from my answer without refering to it is also not very kosher!

Comment: Sorry if you feel harmed. Since your answer was a starting point and a part of this question I assume you're still credited for your work. If you want I can correct my answer and put your name on part of your code.